# How to share only text on facebook messenger for ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to share only text from my ios app to facebook messenger. I searched all around google and stackoverflow but i didn't find any useful information.

Is there any way that I can share only text not link or photo or video ?

Comment: No. The text the user needs to type themself